# Whether to change supervisor in UK Masters degree when supervisor is not providing much feedback and says I can change supervisor if I want?

Tags: thesis, advisor

I am pursuing a taught Master's degree in UK, and my field is social science. I was assigned to a dissertation supervisor by department. My supervisor is a very nice person with good personality, he is also tenured and respected in department.

The problem is that I can not get much feedback from him. I did two classes with him, and during these classes I talked with him about my class projects. I got an impression that he does not care much about what we do in our assignments or dissertation. The results from my assignments under him, did not make me happy, compared to the results I achieved from other classes.

The main problem is, I observe a similar trend for my dissertation work. He does not seem very interested in, probably he is too busy with his own research and other duties. But, at the end of the day, this affects the quality of the work done, and I am totally lost.

I talked with him about this issue and my concerns about the dissertation. He said that he believes I will do good work, but, also he pointed that I am free to apply for an advisor change (though, viability of this is unknown).

I am not sure if he is politely telling me that he wants me to leave or stay. What kind of path should I follow ?

Comment: Becky is right.  "I am not sure if he is politely telling me that he wants me to leave or stay."  He may be saying he is depressed and can't do a good job advising you, and you should take care of yourself by withdrawing from him.  He may be saying he is selfish and doesn't want the responsibility of working closely with someone and providing true advising.  He may be saying he's got Asperger's and that is preventing him from acting like a mensch.

Answer (score 3):

Just try to talk to your department chair/graduate program coordinator and see what they say. If they have no problems with you changing advisors, then just go ahead and talk to other faculty members.